# How to update Datagrid with an ItemsSource that doesn't know when an item is added?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I know I Should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface if I want to notify the grid that it should update for the properties in the items, So I did and it was working before.

I decided to change the getter of the bound `ObservableCollection` so that it would be relative to my DataController class. This way, the `Add()` method is never called so in theory, the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler` is never called. Does that sound about right?

This is the grid:

[image: Bound grid]

De grid is bound to my TeamQualificationMatches collection residing in the `ViewModel`:

```
public ObservableCollection<TeamMatchModel> TeamQualificationMatches
{
    get 
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<TeamMatchModel>(App.Data.GetDoubleTeamMatches().Where(
            match => match.TournamentId == CurrentTournament.Id &&
                     match.Status == MatchStatus.QualificationsPlaying).ToList<TeamMatchModel>());
    }
}
```

And most of the `TeamMatchModel` instances implement `OnPropertyChanged`:

```
public string Notes
{
    get { return _teamMatch.Notes; }
    set
    {
        _teamMatch.Notes = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Notes");
    }
}
```

My logic used to work when my `TeamQualificationMatches` were as follows:

```
private ObservableCollection<TeamMatchModel> _teamQualificationMatches = new ObservableCollection<TeamMatchModel>();
public ObservableCollection<TeamMatchModel> TeamQualificationMatches
{
    get
    {
        return _teamQualificationMatches;
    }
}
```

When I'm changing the status of a `TeamMatchModel` instance, I do call `OnPropertyChanged("TeamQualificationMatches")`. So I don't know why the grid doesn't reflect on this update.

```
public MatchStatus Status
{
    get { return (MatchStatus)_teamMatch.Status; }
    set 
    {
        _teamMatch.Status = (int)value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Status");
        switch (value)
        {
            case MatchStatus.QualificationsPlaying:
                OnPropertyChanged("TeamQualificationMatches");
                break;
            case MatchStatus.PreselectionsPlaying:
                OnPropertyChanged("TeamPreSelectionMatches");
                break;
            case MatchStatus.RoundAPlaying:
                OnPropertyChanged("TeamWinnerMatches");
                break;
            case MatchStatus.RoundBPlaying:
                OnPropertyChanged("TeamLoserMatches");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

It must be something simple that I'm overlooking. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't bind the UI to a property in the view model that always gives a new value. This is why your original version works. Adding and removing items from the observable collection should update the UI as it implements INotifyCollectionChanged. So keep a single observable collection, bind it to the UI and when you need to just clear it and replace the items.

Comment: I understand, but I wanted to dynamically assemble my collections by working with statuses. Figuring I would be able to explicitly call `OnPropertyChanged` for a collection. This avoids the need to change the status AND manually updating the collection. Is that in any way possible?

Comment: You could try using CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView on your data which will get you an ICollectionView. Bind this and change the Filter property when you need to change the view.

Comment: Doesn't WPF bind directly to the DefaultView of a collection by default? And could a filter eliminate the need for the getter for my collection as described in my question (binding directly to the collection in my datacontroller class)?

Comment: Calling CVS.DefaultView(collection) does binding magic under the covers (necessary evil from a bygone era apparently) so you don't technically need to bind to the collection view. However, I always force myself to because this is black magic in my view and a potential maintenance headache. In 6 months time when you look at it then an ICollectionView property is better than a 'stealth bound' enumerable. 

In terms of binding, you wouldn't need to try to bind to a new collection any more but you will still need to bind something to the data grid.

Comment: You may be right, I've been reading about CollectionViews on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and it seems useful to invest time in a better understanding. Thanks

Comment: You were right about this. I reversed back to the way it was and made a lot of improvements since then. Thanks